# Python remove from beginning to first specific character in a string?

Tags: python, string, split

Assuming I have the following string:

```
this is ;a cool test
```

How can I remove everything from the start up to the first time a `;` occurs?
The expected output would be `a cool test`.

I only know how to remove a fixed amount of characters using the bracket notation, which is not helpful here because the location of the `;` is not fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Using `str.find` and slicing.

**Ex:**

```
s = "this is ;a cool test; Hello World."
print(s[s.find(";")+1:])
# --> a cool test; Hello World.
```

---

Or using `str.split`

**Ex:**

```
s = "this is ;a cool test; Hello World."
print(s.split(";", 1)[-1])
# --> a cool test; Hello World.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex

```
import re
x = "this is ;a cool test"
x = re.sub(r'^[^;]+;','',x)
print(x)
```